# Multi threaded access requested by thread Thread[pool-2-thread-1,5,main] but is not allowed for language(s) js

Tags: karate

I'm converting about 2800 tests from Karate 0.9.6 to Karate 1.1.0.  While going through the breaking changes and refactoring the existing tests I'm encountering a lot of tests randomly failing due to the error:

> Multi threaded access requested by thread Thread[pool-2-thread-1,5,main] but is not allowed for language(s) js.

These are for different reasons all over the place.  Most are from Background steps but not all.  Here are a few cases that fail:

`* configure headers = { cache-control: 'no-cache' , Accept: 'application/fhir+json' }`

`* def authToken = callonce read('classpath:com/company/tests/token/AuthToken.feature')`

`And header Access-Control-Request-Headers = 'Content-Type'`

I tried to create a project to duplicate the issue but it seems random.  Are there known issues with this?

Answer (score 0):

I really hope that it is this issue: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1725

Which will be easy to confirm, just upgrade to 1.2.0.RC1

If that doesn't work, that will be extremely bad news and you will have to submit a way to replicate.

And do note that the new JS engine doesn't like Java or JS functions being passed around in `callSingle()` or `callonce`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karatecallsingle (see the paragraph that begins with `IMPORTANT:`)